# Can Window Detect It's In Lightview Mode?

Tags: window, mode

Is there a way to find out if a window is opening in lightview? I have a notification system program that shows up on all pages of the website. I don't want it to show up on pages that open in lightview mode. Is there a way to detect that without having to list all the pages that shouldn't use this notification system?

Answer (score 0):

I found checking for window==top works well.

```
if(window!=top){
// run the program
}
```